# MvvmCross - missing viewmodels parameters with Link all assemblies enabled

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

Trying to reduce an app size, I enabled 'Link all assemblies' option on my Xamarin.iOS app. Unfortunately, when I launch the app, passing simple view model parameters doesn't work. On the application output I can see the following warning:

`mvx:Diagnostic:  1.93 Missing parameter for call to ViewModel - missing parameter isLaunchedForTheFirstTime - assuming null - this may fail for value types! 

mvx:Error:  1.94 Failed to parse BoolParser parameter isLaunchedForTheFirstTime from string`

I have no idea what to add to LinkerPleaseInclude.cs to make it work. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Here's my preserve.xml file which contains all referenced assemblies:
http://pastebin.com/cEmLDxqn

And my view model navigation:

```
ShowViewModel<FirstViewModel>(new {isLaunchedForTheFirstTime = true})

[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class FirstViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    //properties
    public void Init(bool isLaunchedForTheFirstTime)
    {
        //handling parameter
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not all the time the linker is smart enough to detect everything that you need for you project to run, especially if you're using DI or reflection. In these cases, you can [configure](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/custom_linking/) it to include the assemblies/types or methods that it might've missed.

Comment: Sure you're right. I'm aware of that. But the question is which type is responsible for passing viewmodel's parameters...

Comment: I have no experience with mvvmcross myself but have you tried adding mvvmcross assembly and maybe your viewmodel type and all its dependencies? If that works, then slowly narrow it down until it breaks again. I've had problems like this before and the only way I've fixed it is by trial and error. There is no fast way unfortunately, but perhaps someone can pop in and give us ideas.

Comment: I've tried it with no luck. Even if I include all referenced assemblies, there's still problem with passing parameters. I add preserve.xml file from my project

Comment: Is the isLaunchedForTheFirstTime your variable? Can I see what your ViewModel class looks like?

Comment: Instead of using an anonymous type, try making it strong-typed and see if that works. Try adding `Preserve` to the type as well if it doesn't work the first time.

Comment: The issue disappeared when I switched from -xml=preserve.xml to linkskip a subset of my referenced assemblies. Any ideas what's the difference between those two? I'm adding the same subset in both methods

Comment: Any answer on this?